# Help with atk4-web, atk4-example ver. 4.03

Tags: atk4

I don't now where can I find help. None forums about atk4.
Can you help me, please?

atk4-web (4.0.3):

How run atk4-web localy, where is site dump (mysql database)?
What is mean this error:
No such tag (version) in template for Object AgileToolkitWeb(agile_project). Tags are: page_title, page_title#1, seo_keywords, seo_keywords#2, seo_descr, seo_descr#3, template, template#4, template#5, template#6, template#7, template#8, template#9, os, os#10, js_include, js_include#11, document_ready, document_ready#12, section, section#13, template#14, menu_about, menu_about#15, page, page#16, menu_doc, menu_doc#17, page#18, menu_develop, menu_develop#19, page#20, menu_services, menu_services#21, page#22, menu_download, menu_download#23, page#24, menu_blog, menu_blog#25, page#26, link_comparison, link_comparison#27, link_example, link_example#28, link_tour, link_tour#29, Content, Content#30, TabContent, TabContent#40

D:\Www\atk4web\atk4\lib\SMlite.php:341

atk4-example (4.0.3):

Why page has not javascrip included, when I allow ->check() in Frontend?
What is difference between empty.html and shared.html?
empty.html:

shared.html:

1. Why I got error when I did change in empty.html to:

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Agile Toolkit uses template engine called 'SMlite'. Its very basic and allows you to load template, then set tags to a certain value.

$tpl->trySet('mytag',123);

Views in Agile Toolkit rely on this template engine and will try to generate their output and place inside parent's template. In your case object was instructed to use spot which did not exist in the template.

Read section about adding here: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/learn, it should be helpful.

There are no need for JavaScript on auth login form. It also bypasses some of the UI/functionality due to security reasons. You can either create your own empty.html by placing it into template/jui/empty.html (without atk4) and enable javascript in there.

Also sequence of adding jUI and executing auth->check() might change this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Added: https://github.com/atk4/atk4-web/commit/39712ff4c735b2323a0cea06e4a51691bcc9c874#diff-1 Enjoy.